# Unable to compile transcluded directives in unit test as of Angular 1.3.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a directive with `transclude: true`.  It includes a `template` property that points to a simple HTML file with one element that contains an `ng-transclude` attribute on an anchor element.  The anchor element wraps the content of the directive.

My test looks like this:

```js
describe('foobar directive', function() {
    var $compile, $rootScope, $modal;

    beforeEach(module('collective'));
    beforeEach(module('test.templates'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$modal_) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $modal = _$modal_;
    }));

    it('attempts to open the modal when the wrapped element is clicked', function() {
        spyOn($modal, 'open');

        var el = $compile('<foo-bar><div id="foobar"></div></foo-bar>')($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();

        el.find('#foobar').click();
        expect($modal.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Note that I'm using ng-html2js-preprocessor to load my templates into the test.templates module. That seems to be working fine for all other non transcluded directives.

The test above fails as `$modal.open()` is never called.  It is never called as the anchor element in the template is never added to the element after it is compiled.  This is not an issue in my running app, nor was it an issue with Angular 1.2.9.  The issue starts with Angular 1.3.0, and remains in Angular 1.3.5.

After running `$compile` in my test, the element looks like this:

```html
<foo-bar class="ng-scope">
   <div id="foobar"></div>
</foo-bar>
```

When it should look like this:

```
<foo-bar class="ng-isolate-scope">
   <a href="#" ng-click="blah blah">
      <div id="foobar"></div>
   </a>
</foo-bar>
```

The latter is true of 1.2.9, but not 1.3.0.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Tried to replicate but I couldn't. Can you inject `$templateCache` and do a `console.log` on `$templateCache.get('fooBar.template.html')` just to make sure it's the correct one?

Comment: @tasseKATT I just confirmed that the template in the cache exists and does match the expected template for the directive.  This is not entirely surprising as I have many other directive unit tests that are passing.  The only difference between this one and the others is the fact that this one deals with transclusion.

Comment: **I just checked with Angular#1.3.0 and #1.3.5 and compiling directives with *transcluded* content works fine for me in both cases**. To be specific I made the compilation in the karma test environment like you. How are you sure that `ng-transclude` is **the** problem here? Can you try to use `template:function(){console.log('called')}` instead of `templateUrl` to check if the directive is compiled in the first place (maybe you just mismatched the name of the directive)?

Comment: Two more things: 1. please paste exact code of the directive. 2. unless jQuery loaded `.find` is not supposed to find elements by id.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak A directive name mismatch can't be the issue.  As I mentioned before, the same exact test passes in Angular 1.2.9.  After simply updating to 1.3.x, it fails.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak I'm aware of how `find` works w/ and w/out jQuery.  You're barking up the wrong tree.  Again, all it takes to make the test fail is moving from Angular 1.2.x to 1.3.x.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak I'll edit my question to include the directive shortly.

Comment: @RayNicholus as I wrote: I recreated pretty the same example as yours and compiling works flawless... (both in 1.3.0 and 1.3.5) So just please double check if the template function is called at all.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Surprisingly, it isn't called, and I can't figure out why this is the case.

Comment: Ha!  Found the issue.  Really weird.  Does seem to be attributed to a small behavioral change in 1.3.x.  Turns out one of the services I was injecting was preventing angular from compiling the directive in my test environment.  The dependency in question was a small factory I created that simply makes a property on the `window` an injectable service.  I never actually use this service in my tests, so I don't actually import the underlying library in my karma config, and therefore the property on `window` is undefined.  Angular 1.2.x doesn't seem to care, but 1.3.x chokes and fails to compile!

Comment: @arturgrzesiak I'm going to create an answer that explains the issue a bit more, but you really deserve the points since you helped me down the right path.  Create an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked with Angular#1.3.0 and #1.3.5 and compiling directives with *transcluded* content **works** fine for me in both cases. To be specific I made the compilation in the karma test environment like you.

---

How are you sure that `ng-transclude` is **the** problem here?

Comment: Turns out it's not the problem.  I'll type up an answer explaining the situation and the solution.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @artur, I noticed that the issue was caused by a small change in behavior first introduced into Angular 1.3.0.

Turns out one of the services I was injecting was preventing angular from compiling the directive in my test environment. The dependency in question was a small factory I created that simply makes a property on the window an injectable service. I never actually use this service in my tests, so I don't actually import the underlying library in my karma config, and therefore the property on window is undefined. Angular 1.2.x doesn't seem to care, but 1.3.x chokes and fails to compile!

For example, given this defined factory:

```
myModule.factory('bootbox', function() {
    return window.bootbox;
});
```

...and the following directive:

```
myModule.directive('myDirective', ['$scope', 'bootbox' function($scope, bootbox) {
   //...
}]);
```

The above directive WILL compile if `window.bootbox` is `undefined` in Angular 1.2.x, but it will NOT compile in 1.3.x.  A `null` value doesn't seem to cause this problem, strangely enough.

Comment: Yo dude, did you get any specific error, or was your directive simply not being compiled?